# How can I disable lollipop out transition animation in Android

Tags: android, animation, android-5.0-lollipop, transition

I want added lollipop transitions to my app and it's really great. It's share my view from one activity to another with smooth animation, but I want to disable this animation when I exit from second screen to first screen and I can not find how to do id. My theme has this styles:

```
        <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">false</item>
    <item name="android:fragmentAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">@bool/default_underline_indicator_fades</item>
    <item name="android:fragmentAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">@bool/default_underline_indicator_fades</item>
```

Comment: create theme without transitions and set it to desire activity in manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I find out how to turn of the exit transition. I delete transition name from the view after some delay:

```
 view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    view.setTransitionName("some unused transition name");
                }
            }
        }, 500);
```

And if it's deletes - it won't be shared when activity finish

Comment: You don't have to set a delay for it, and you can just put null value as the transition name. I'd like to ask something though: after using this, I noticed that the transition when pressing back button is just a weird flash between the activities. How come?

Comment: It's your out effect transition animation. I think you can turn off it by using <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@android:transition/no_transition</item>
  <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@android:transition/no_transition</item> in your styles theme

Answer (score 2):

by screens do you mean activities? If so, just call

```
overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
```

after finish() on the second activity

Comment: Yes, I mean activities.But if I do not call finish() explicity? User just press back button. I try to  use overridePendingTransition(0, 0) in onResume() but it does not works.

Answer (score 1):

Just call regular Activity `finish()` method instead of `supportFinishAfterTransition()`

and override back methods

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone is always looking for an answer, you can disable out transition for an activity like this:

```
override fun finishAfterTransition() {
   super.finish()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adding another answer as I cannot paste code in first one. Try

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I do not why, but overridePendingTransition(0, 0) is not working for me. The exit transition is still reproducing

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it works (to disable the exit animation, set shouldShowExitAniamtion to false):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (shouldShowExitAnimation) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should fix "let me if it works". I think you meant "let me know if it works"

Comment: Good catch. Fixed.

Comment: This transition will work on finish... So this answer is unuserfull